# How do I present one article in multiple places and keep its semantics intact?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, article

I'm working on enabling a CMS to presents various parts of an article in different places within a web page.

The CMS provides a grid layout, composed of div elements, into which "boxes" may be placed. Each box may be configured to present a certain part of an article, or anything else for that matter. The authors are allowed to drag-and-drop these boxes around in the grid as they please.

An article may for instance describe a division within an organisation, containing a textual summary of the devision, contact information and upcoming events hosted by the division. One box may be set up to present the summary, another box may present the contact information, and a third box may present the upcoming events in a calendar design format.

As long as all three boxes are placed in that order within the same div in the grid, wrapping them all in an article tag will provide the semantics needed to inform anyone that all three boxes present different aspects of the same article. But what happens when boxes with unrelated content are inserted between the three? Here's a simplified example:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="box">
        ... Related division corporate speak ...
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        ... Related division contact info ...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="ads">
    <div class="box">
        ... Unrelated advertisement ...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <div class="box">
        ... Unrelated login form ...
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        ... Related division events calendar ...
    </div>
</div>
```

As far as I know, there is no way to explicitly specify that each of the three boxes are all related, using a standard HTML attribute.

Is it possible at all to maintain the article's semantic integrity once it has been divided like this? Does schema.org markup offer any help here?

PS: Cheating my way to a visual equivalent presentation using CSS positioning tricks is not an option.

Comment: (1) When you say "article", do you mean the HTML5 element `article`, or the general meaning (i.e., written work, piece of content, post, etc)? -- (2) Is the unrelated content absolutely unrelated, or is there *some* relation to the content? (for example, an advertisement could be about a camera, while your article is about photography) -- (3) Can there be several articles on one page?

Comment: unor: (1) written work, but also HTML5 article element eligible. (2) Assume totally unrelated, like a login form. (3) Yes, but this is not a requirement